# Python | Aiogram Как прикрепить фото к тексту, а не текст к фото?

Tags: python, aiogram, photo

Пытаюсь найти метод для отправки текста с фото, но у меня выходит наоборот.

- Что получается:

[image: Фото сверху текста]

- Что хочу получить:

[image: Желаемый результат (Картинка не является ссылкой и на нее нет отсылок в тексте!)]

На втором фото, картинка не является ссылкой и на нее нет упоминаний в тексте выше.
Есть отдельные боты, которые могут такое делать, но подобного решения в документации я не видел.

Знающие люди, подскажите, как быть в этой ситуации?

Comment: Пожалуйста, исправьте вопрос, чтобы он отражал конкретную проблему с достаточным количеством деталей для возможности дать адекватный ответ.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Это делается с помощью ссылки (если телеграмм обнаружит по ссылке картинку, то он покажет её превью прямо в сообщении), например:

```
from aiogram.types import ParseMode

...

text = 'simple_text'
img_url = 'https://i.stack.imgur.com/L44O9.png'
await bot.send_message(user_id, f'{text}<a href="{img_url}">.</a>', parse_mode=ParseMode.HTML)
```