# Вопрос с отправкой текста + фото с помощью telegram bot

Tags: telegram-bot, aiogram

Как отправлять именно текст + фото, чтобы фото было снизу, видел как это делают через HTML разметку, но там показывается как брать фото с инета, а в моем боте все фотки уже в отдельном файле. При попытки смены ссылки `scr` у меня выдает ошибку. Есть ли какая-та статья где наглядно это все показывается

Comment: ответ дан здесь https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1424453/python-aiogram-Как-прикрепить-фото-к-тексту-а-не-текст-к-фото

Comment: там описана реализация в виде ссылки на картинку, а я хочу вставить картинку с моего пк

Comment: Ну тогда только `send_photo(msg.chat.id, photo=InputFile(path_to_file), caption="text")`

Comment: Ибо сделать так как автор того вопроса, с помощью картинок с пк невозможно. Разве что вы их захостите где-то, и будете ссылаться через тот способ который был в той теме.